# UVM. How do get a report of which sequence is currently running on a sequencer?

Tags: uvm

How do I get a report of which sequence is currently running on a sequencer?
This is for debugging only ... I can already see I have a problem. What I want is a bit more debugging info. There are multiple sequences that can run and I want to know which is queued up to. I'd settle for getting the information (sequence by name) from the driver after get_next_item unblocks, but I don't see how to do that either.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a handle to the sequencer, then you can use the methods provided in uvm_sequencer_base class to get the current sequence executing.

```
uvm_sequencer m_seqr; // This is your sequencer pointer
if (m_seqr.is_grabbed()) begin
  uvm_sequence cur_seq = m_seqr.current_grabber();
  `uvm_info(get_name(), $psprintf("Current sequence executing is %s", cur_seq.get_name(), UVM_MEDIUM)
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a try later and post how it went.

Comment: OK. Please let us know and accept the answer if it works

Comment: When I got back to this I realized that I wasn't clear before. I don't want to know the current grabber ... I want to know which sequence is queued up to run. There _is_ no grabbing or locking, that's why it's broken. But it's broken with odd behaviour and before I fix it properly I want more information. I run on the "if you didn't fix it, it's not fixed" idea, so I want to verify exactly what's happening before I simply make the problem go away with proper coding.

Comment: Please clear up your question with maybe some code or a small example. Right now, I am not sure what you mean by queued up? Are you randomly picking sequences from sequence_lib? Please clarify

Comment: I think any example just gets away from the base question, How do I get a report of which sequence is queued up to run? "Queued" is straight out of the class reference ... their terminology, not mine (I just adopt it).

Comment: Which class? uvm_sequence? Can you please point to a link that describes these queues? I am more curious now than having an answer

Comment: I got an answer here:https://verificationacademy.com/forums/uvm/how-do-get-report-which-sequence-currently-running-sequencer

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for the info